# jQuery: Does selector specificity increase performance with .on() delegation?

Tags: jquery, performance, delegation, event-delegation

Is there a performance gain when increasing specificity in delegated event binding with `.on()`?

How does one test for this?

For example, is the second statement more performant than the first:

```
$('.foo').on('mouseenter', ':has(.other)', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});

$('.bar').on('mouseenter', 'button:has(.other)', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

```js
$('.foo').on('mouseenter', ':has(.other)', function (e) {
  console.log(e);
});

$('.bar').on('mouseenter', 'button:has(.other)', function (e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```css
.foo, .bar {
  margin: 2em auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <button type="button">Hello
    <span class="other">World</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <button type="button">Hello
    <span class="other">World</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

My main concern is that listening for `mouseenter` events with delegation is a performance drain and if there is a way to test for performance on this type of event handler.

**Update**

I should clarify that I'm not looking to understand the performance implications of using delegation in general. I'm hoping to understand the performance implications of using delegation with `mouseenter` during user interaction (as the user's mouse enters both delegated and non-delegated elements within the bound element) and if there is a performance gain by using a more specific selector for delegation.

My inclination is to assume there isn't because every event has to bubble up to the bound element before being checked against the delegated selector.

But is there a way to test for this?

Comment: Tried running any jsperf tests?

Comment: If anything, I would think the 2nd version would be negligibly *less* performant. They're both going to bubble up to the ancestor anyway, and the second version requires checking node type as well as class presence.

Comment: How could I run a jsperf test on this specific example? Doesn't jsperf just test runtime performance, such as the binding operations themselves, as opposed to event handling on user interaction?

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: LOL. This isn't premature. I'm working on an enterprise app that may have thousands of DOM elements to traverse. This is a paired down example to be sure.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm not looking to understands the performance implications of using delegation. I'm hoping to understand the performance implications of using delegation with `mouseenter` and if there is a performance gain by using a more specific selector for delegation. My inclination is to assume there isn't because every event has to bubble up to the bound element before being checked against the delegated selector. But is there a way to test for this?

Comment: I would suggest that, in general terms, using `:has` in a `closest` call (as `on` does behind the scenes) is going to have *woeful* performance. I would test for `button` in the selector and then use the `.has()` method in the callback.

Comment: @lonesomeday That makes sense, but unfortunately I may only bind directly to a container element that will receive the buttons at a later time. The contents of this container may be re-rendered any number of times, so delegation is a must.

Comment: @gfullam I'm sure that delegation is the right option. However, I would go to great effort to make sure that the [`:has` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) is not in your selector string. It is a jQuery selector, not a native browser one, and so is very slow. You're using it on every element in the tree. If you do another test, say `button`, then use the [`.has` function](http://api.jquery.com/has) to test that element, it will have much better performance since it can use the browser's inbuilt capabilities better.

Comment: @lonesomeday I had gone to great lengths originally to avoid delegation because I need to bind to the parent of a known child class selector, unfortunately the only way to do this is with `:has` because you can't chain `.has` with delegated selectors — it can only chain to existing DOM elements and at the time of binding, the elements aren't there. It is because of my use of `:has` that I am concerned about finding other performance gains. It is also important to me to understand what's happening and how to test for performance in this situation.

Comment: @gfullam I realise that. I'm saying that you should try to take `:has` out of the selector and do the test in the event callback; it will have much better performance. See [these two examples](http://jsfiddle.net/96t74umd/): they are functionally equivalent, but the first has much better performance.

Comment: @lonesomeday I like that example. And its getting close to answering my question. Can you post it as an answer with an explanation of ''why'' the one function is more performant than the other? How do you determine the performance difference between the two?

Comment: Eventually figured a way to formulate a jsperf test that shows that using `:has` in the selector is more often (in repeated tests) performant than using `.has` in the handler; it also shows that increasing specificity, as in `button:has` in the selector, consistently improved performance. See: http://jsperf.com/has-filter-in-delegated-event-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Specificity helps… a little.

According to [this JSPerf test](http://jsperf.com/has-filter-in-delegated-event-selector/2), adding specificity to the selector in the posted examples consistently improves performance in repeated tests, but the gains could conceivably be considered negligible at the user interaction level where events are occurring sporadically in relatively small iterations.

In some tests, the difference was small enough and within the margin of error to be considered statistically equivalent.

### Selector filtering in the handler hurts

But the most surprising result is that of an ancillary third test suggested by one of the commenters above which takes `:has()` out of the selector and replaces it with a `.has()` check in the callback function, which consistently performs slower than using `:has()` in the selector — often by 100 operations per second or more.

This is arguably less negligible and especially remarkable considering that the [jQuery documentation for `:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) indicates that you should expect better performance here:

> Because `:has()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using `:has()` cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()`
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `$(
>   "your-pure-css-selector" ).has( selector/DOMElement )` instead.

I don't doubt that in a selector statement where `.has()` is simply used to reduce the set of matched elements, that one could expect better performance; but I suspect the performance drain demonstrated in the test is the result of breaking that convention by moving the `.has()` check into an event handler where event data is being passed around, a new jQuery object is being constructed from `this`, and `.length` is being accessed and checked in an `if` statement.

---

### Test formulation

To formulate the test, three event binding benchmarks were configured and applied to the same HTML markup, then the same event-triggering test case — simulating a user mousing over various delegated and non-delegated elements on the screen — was applied to each of the three benchmarks for comparison.

**Benchmark 1:**

```
    $('.foo').on('mouseenter', ':has(.other)', function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
```

**Benchmark 2:**

```
    $('.foo').on('mouseenter', 'button:has(.other)', function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
```

**Benchmark 3:**

```
    $('.foo').on('mouseenter', 'button', function(e) {
      if ($(this).has('.other').length) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="foo">
    <button type="button" id="A">some text</button>
    <button type="button" id="B"><span class="other">some text</span></button>
    <div id="C">some text</div>
</div>
```

**Test case:**

```
$('#A').trigger('mouseenter');
$('#B').trigger('mouseenter');
$('#C').trigger('mouseenter');
```

[image: Screenshot of table showing JSPerf test results]